# Save json response for n minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

It's takes around 1.5s to get response from api, so I thought I might just save response every n minute and then instead of making call to api inside command I would just return saved response. So my question is what is a best way to do it? Since api response is very long i don't think its good thing to save it to db.
Or maybe every time command called just make a call to api and then save it somewhere for n minutes and if command been called again in this n period of time just get saved response instead of calling api every time.

I'm just not sure how and where to save response.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
let data = await fetch('apiurl').then(body => body.json());
```

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: welcome to SO. Try to implement server side caching, this should help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache

In the future, please remember to post what you've tried with code examples, as this question is quite broad in scope.

Comment: I don't have any specific code since I have no idea with what to start, I just have a basic api call and thats it

Comment: Beke, I would lean toward a memory cache if you are talking minutes.

Comment: @Bibberty I started using node-cache (thx to Steven Stark), another question, is it a good practice to make an api call every 1-5 mins?

Comment: It's case by case. If you data is volatile then you call as often as it might change. For fairly static data consider longer caching with a hash token to check with server. You can also use the http protocols to return an I change response

Comment: @StevenStark is there any pros using `node-cache` compare to answer from Bibberty?

Comment: @Beke Yes, the answer from Bibberty correctly answers your question, however using a proper library handles much more than the bare bones solution, but locks you in to doing things the way the library wants you to do things. pros and cons. This is a well established lib on it's 3rd major release with a lot of features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example (very simple one I know) we have a memory cache and refresh if older than 5 secs.

```js
const dummyGetLiveData = () => {
  return { "data": "value" }
};

let cache;
let maxCacheAgeInMilliseconds = 5000; // 5secs

const provideData = () => {
  if(!cache || (Date.now() - cache.timeStamp > maxCacheAgeInMilliseconds) ) {
    console.log('Cache Build');
    cache = {
      timeStamp: Date.now(),
      data: dummyGetLiveData()
    }
  }
  return cache.data;  
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(provideData());
});
```

```html
<button>Get Data</button>
```